# What will be minimum variance unbiased estimator?

Tags: probability, estimation

Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be a random sample from a distribution with p.d.f.,
$$f(x;\theta)=\theta^2xe^{-x\theta} ; 0<x<\infty, \theta>0$$ Obtain minimum variance unbiased estimator of $\theta$ and examine whether it is attained?

MY WORK:

Using MLE i have found the estimator for $\theta=\frac{2}{\bar{x}}$
Or as $$X\sim Gamma(2, \theta)$$So 
$E(X)=2\theta$
$E(\frac{x}{2})=\theta$
so can i take $\frac {x}{2}$ as unbiased estimator of $\theta$.
I'm stuck and confused need some help.

Thank u.

Comment: Crossposted at math.SE as per comment suggesting that over there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28779/what-will-be-minimum-variance-unbiased-estimator-for-this

Comment: @amul28 You probably want to limit your search to *linear* estimators; otherwise, this question might be difficult to answer.

Comment: @whuber, or rather, *functions* of linear estimators. I've posted an answer on math.SE where this question originated.

Comment: @cardinal I don't follow.  Since $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ are individually linear estimators, the most general function of a set of linear estimators is just--any function of the data.  You seem to be making no effective distinction.  Do you mean functions of a *single* linear form in the data?

Comment: @whuber, just slightly sloppy wording on my part, as I suppose it could be interpreted in at least two ways. "Functions of *a* linear estimator" would probably have been clearer.

Comment: @whuber, looks like your edit to your comment and my response to the original one got crossed in the ether.